# Which club started the tradition of ball juggling during the presentation of newly signed player?

Tags: football, history, transfer

When clubs sign new players they usually organise a presentation for them, where players juggle the ball. I'm wondering which club/player started this tradition.

E.g, here is the [video](https://youtu.be/Qr2SRSq8gC8?t=42s) of Real Madrid's new signing Vinícius Júnior juggling the ball during his presentation.

Comment: The oldest I have found so far is of [Diego Maradona at Napoli (1984)](https://youtu.be/6RMouRKfBrI).